# One table multiple fields to other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

So I have a table with all user information and another table with product information.

On each product there is a reference to multiple users.
e.g.: user1 is producer, user2 is productSupervisor and user3 is productManager.

How can I get information like this:
product1.producer is User1.Name, product1.supervisor is user2.Name and product.manager is user3.Name

producer, productSupervisor and productManager are stored as userID.

Create Statements

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  idEmployee int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  networkID varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  firstName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  lastName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  phoneExtension varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  mobile varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  onCall tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  lastLogin varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Never',
  active tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  createDate timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (idEmployee),
  KEY idx_employee (idTeam),
  KEY idx_employee_0 (idPosition),
  CONSTRAINT fk_employee_employeepositions FOREIGN KEY (idPosition) REFERENCES employeePositions (idPosition) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_employee_teams FOREIGN KEY (idTeam) REFERENCES teams (idTeam) ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE product (
  idProduct int(11) NOT NULL,
  idSupervisor int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  idProducer int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  idManager int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  prodcutInfo longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY idProduct 
 )
```

Comment: `select product_id, user1.name, user2.name, user3.name
left join users on product.user1_id = users.user_id user1
left join users on product.user2_id = users.user_id user2
left join users on product.user3_id = users.user_id user3
where product_id = ?`

Comment: Or something - as @ryanVincent says, it'd be much easier to help if we had an idea of what the query should actually look like :)

Comment: I havent inserted any data yet....i'm still trying to wrap my head around the structure...to know if I need to change the structure. But i can't find a way to have the query making sense.

Comment: The reply from @Mureinik got me where i wanted....and now i feel stupid...I can call the same table multiple times on the same query.. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the `product` table on the `employee` table thrice, once for each role:

```
SELECT idProduct, 
       CONCAT_WS(' ', s.firstname, s.lastname) AS supervisor,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', p.firstname, p.lastname) AS producer,
       CONCAT_WS(' ', m.firstname, m.lastname) AS manager
FROM   product pr
JOIN   employee s ON pr.idSupervisor = s.idEmployee
JOIN   employee p ON pr.idSupervisor = p.idEmployee
JOIN   employee m ON pr.idSupervisor = m.idEmployee
```

Comment: That's it....!!i can call the same table multiples...I'm going to close myself on a dark room now...!!Thanks a lot for the help